# Get in WooCommerce cart the product ID of a cart item

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, product

```
$cart_item = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
```

I have the above code.

if I run print_r on cart_item I get a multi dimensional array:

```
Array(    [a6292668b36ef412fa3c4102d1311a62] => Array        (            [product_id] => 6803
```

How do I get the product_id only?

I tried $test = `$cart_item['data'];`

```
print_r($test);
```

Didn't work.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

To get the **`product ID`** of each cart item in the foreach loop (for a simple product):

```
foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
    $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];
}
```

If it's a variable product, to get the **`variation ID`**:

```
foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
    $variation_id = $cart_item['variation_id'];
}
```

Or for both cases *(where* `$cart_item['data']` *is the* `WC_Product` *Object in Woocommerce 3+)*:

```
foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
    // compatibility with WC +3
    if( version_compare( WC_VERSION, '3.0', '<' ) ){
        $product_id = $cart_item['data']->id; // Before version 3.0
    } else {
        $product_id = $cart_item['data']->get_id(); // For version 3 or more
    }
}
```

---

> **Update:** Using Product ID outside the loop

1) Breaking the loop *(Just to get the first item ID (product ID) of cart)*:

```
foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
    $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];
    break;
}
```

You can use directly `$product_id` variable of the first item in cart.

---

2) Using an array of product IDs *(one for each item in cart)*.

```
$products_ids_array = array();

foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
    $products_ids_array[] = $cart_item['product_id'];
}
```

- To get the 1st item product ID: **`$products_ids_array[0];`**
- To get the 2nd item product ID: **`$products_ids_array[1];`**  etc…

---

To check **product categories** or **product tags** in cart item use WordPress [`has_term()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term) like:

```
foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
    // For product categories (term IDs, term slugs or term names)
    if( has_term( array('clothing','music'), 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] ) ) {
        // DO SOMETHING
    }

    // For product Tags (term IDs, term slugs or term names)
    if( has_term( array('clothing','music'), 'product_tag', $cart_item['product_id'] ) ) {
        // DO SOMETHING ELSE
    }
}
```

> We always use `$cart_item['product_id']` as we get the parent variable product when a cart item is a product variation.
>
> Product variations don't handle any custom taxonomy as product categories and product tags

Comment: does it have to be in a for loop?

Comment: can i use $product_id outside the for loop?

Comment: @Kevin.a Yes it have to be in a loop because you can have more than one item in cart and it's pretty complicated to get this with the cart key item (as you have mention it on your question: `Array(    [a6292668b36ef412fa3c4102d1311a62]`). Yes, you can use this ID outside the loop, **see my update**.